# Complex calculus problem

Tags: complex-analysis

For the following question:

There is an entire function $z^2+Bz$, find $B$ so that $|f(B)|=|B|$ and at z=0 the map defines a rotation through $\theta =\pi /4$.

I do not understand what it means with rotation through an angle at a point. Can anyone explain? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At $z\approx 0$ the function is mainly $Bz$, so $\arg B=\frac\pi4$. The first condition results in $|2B^2|=|B|$, where only $|B|=\frac12$ is compatible with the other condition. Now you know the polar coordinates of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition in $z=0$ means that the differential of $f$ at $0$ (which is a linear transformation of the complex plane, i.e. a map of the type $az$ with $a=f^\prime (0)\in \mathbb{C}$) is a $\frac{\pi}{4}$-rotation.
 Since a $\theta$-rotation is represented by multiplication against a suitable complex exponential, namely $e^{\imath \theta}$, your condition translates into $f^\prime (0)\cdot z = r e^{\imath\ \frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot z$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ (here $r>0$ is a real scaling factor).

On the other hand, $f^\prime (0) = B$, hence $B=re^{\imath \frac{\pi}{4}}$.

The condition on the module of $f(B)$, i.e. $|f(B)|=|B|$, may be rewritten as $2r^2=r$, from which $r=0$ or $r=1/2$. 
Since only the latter solution is $>0$, you find $B=\frac{1}{2} e^{\imath \frac{\pi}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} + \imath \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$.